# Reactrouter Match property

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a functional component that takes in state from Redux as props.

```
    function Main(props){
      const { dishes, promotions, leaders, comments, resetFeedbackForm, postFeedback, fetchDishes, fetchComments, fetchPromos, fetchLeaders, postComment } = props
      useEffect(() => {
        fetchDishes();
        fetchComments();
        fetchPromos();
        fetchLeaders();
      },[]);

      return (
        <div>
          <div className="container">
          <Header />
            <Switch>
              <Route path='/home' component={() => <HomePage dishes={dishes} promotions={promotions} leaders={leaders} />}/>
              <Route exact path='/menu' component={() => <Menu {...props} dishes={dishes} />} />
              <Route path='/menu/:dishId' component={() => <DishWithId {...props}  />} /> 
              {/*<Route path='/menu/:dishId' component={ DishWithId } /> */}
              <Redirect to="/home" />
            </Switch>
          <Footer />  
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    };

const DishWithId = (props) => {
      console.log(props.match);
      return(
        <div></div>

      );
    };
```

**I pass this props back to my DishWithId component as following:**

- I use ...props to ensure I carry over the  match, location, history props also.

```
< Route path='/menu/:dishId' component={() => <DishWithId {...props}  />} />
```

**When I browse to http://localhost/menu/0 and look at the props the MATCH prop does not contain the correct url.**

```
match: {path: "/", url: "/", params: {…}, isExact: false}
```

**It does work if I simply pass the component, but as I also need to pass the other props, dishes, comments.**

```
<Route path='/menu/:dishId' component={ DishWithId } />
match: {path: "/menu/:dishId", url: "/menu/1", isExact: true, params: {…}}
```

**Any ideas why match is not working when I am using:**

```
<Route path='/menu/:dishId' component={() => <DishWithId {...props}  />} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to get the router props from the parameters of the callback function you provide and pass those on to the component you render:

```
<Route path='/menu/:dishId' component={(routerProps) => <DishWithId {...props} {...routerProps}  />} />
```

Comment: yes well done thank you. Seems is if you add {...props} after and without passing routerProps it gets overwritten.